# How to get array of data in the Success page in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, symfony-1.4

I am fetching data from datatabase in Symfony 1.4.

The problem is that i am not able to access that array in the Success page using `foreach` loop and `print_r()`.

The error is

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

But when I do same thing in the Action page after the Query is executed I am able to get the data using `foreach()` and `print_r($result)`.

Why I am not able to get that array in the success page?

The query and the loop I am using is below:

```
$birthSearchQuery = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('a.bir_le_reg,a.bir_le_dob,b.bir_le_district')
            ->from('BirthLegalInfo as a')
            ->innerJoin('a.BirthStatisticalInfo as b')
            ->Where('bir_le_reg_no IS NOT NULL')
            ->andwhere('bir_le_birth_state =' . $birthState)
            ->andwhere('bir_le_birth_district =' . $birthDistrict)
            ->andwhere('YEAR(bir_le_dob)=' .$birthFromYear);

      $result = $birthSearchQuery->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

It is returning me a array of arrays using `print_r($result)` like this

```
Array
    (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [bir_le_reg] => Delhi
        [bir_le_district] => Delhi
        [bir_le_dob] => 2015
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [bir_le_reg] => Delhi
        [bir_le_district] => Delhi
        [bir_le_dob] => 2014
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [bir_le_reg] => Delhi
        [bir_le_district] => Delhi
        [bir_le_dob] => 2015
    )
)
```

The foreach loop I am using is as

```
foreach($result as $value){
    echo $value['bir_le_district'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $value['bir_le_reg'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $value['bir_le_dob'];
}
```

Comment: Please post your entire action code.

Comment: @Alik Sir the action has lots of code, what j0k told me, worked for me and I am able to print values in template but it has raised another problem, which I have posted below, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a variable to the template in symfony 1.x you should prefix it by `$this->`.

In your case, you should do that:

```
$this->result = $birthSearchQuery->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

Then, in your template, you can call:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
```

Without any problem.

Comment: It worked, but I am getting:                                   `sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator Object ( [count:sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator:private] => 490 [value:protected] `                                                                               with the array when I use print_r($result). Foreach is still not working due to this I guess.

Comment: You can unescape the value, using `sfOutputEscaper::unescape()`: `foreach (sfOutputEscaper::unescape($result) as $value) {`

Comment: You could also access the `$sf_data` variable in the view to get the unescaped version of your array: `foreach($sf_data->getRaw('result') as $value){...`